# Array reference

Tags: java, arrays

If I create an array of variables:

```
public String a;
public String b;
public String c;

public String[] d = {a,b,c};
```

it will contain {null, null, null};

If I then do this:

```
a = "5";
System.out.println(d[0]);
```

output will be null since `a` was `null` when `d` was initialised.

Is there a way to create an "array of references", so that output in this case would be `5`?

EDIT:
PLOT TWIST!

First part of code is in some class. Second part is in a class that is extending the first one.

Comment: How are you getting `null` from primitives?  Also, those variables haven't been initialized; the code won't compile.

Comment: _"it will contain {null, null, null};"_ No your code won't compile.

Comment: Output will not be null, it will be zero (0), because primitives integers are initialized to zero. Use the object wrappers (`Integer`).

Comment: OKay, my bad, I tried to simplify it too much. I was using Strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `String`s with your own mutable class:

```
class MyString {
    private String value;

    public MyString(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return value;
    }
}
```

Now:

```
public MyString a = new MyString(null);
public MyString b = new MyString(null);
public MyString c = new MyString(null);

public MyString[] d = {a,b,c};

...

a.setValue("5");  // <--
```

You might want to ensure that `a` is not `null` before calling `setValue()`, however.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Why do they need explicit initialization? They're fields, not local variables.

Comment: Because `a.setValue("5")` results in an NPE as you have showed it, and `d` is still `{null, null, null}`.